# Promise rejection failed with chai-as-promised

Tags: promise, q, chai-as-promised

I use chai-as-promised library with promise generated by the q library.
This simple test case should work (the promise must be rejected) or i misunderstand promise feature?

```
bdd.it("Test rejection", function () {
    var promise = q.promise(function (resolve, reject, notify) {
        reject(new Error("test"));
    }).then(function () {
        // Nothing to do
    });
    promise.should.be.rejectedWith(Error);
    return promise;
});
```

This test fail with Error: test (I use Intern as unit test library) althought the below test pass:

```
bdd.it("Test rejection", function () {
    var promise = q.promise(function (resolve, reject, notify) {
        reject(new Error("test"));
    }).should.be.rejectedWith(Error);
    return promise;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library needs you to return the return value of `.rejectedWith()` in order for it to test the assertion. You're just calling `.should.be.rejectedWith()` in the middle of your test, and it can't do anything with that.

If you look at the [documentation for chai-as-promised](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/), you can see that this is precisely what they are doing in their examples:

```
return promise.should.be.rejectedWith(Error);
```

The same is true for other promise-based assertions like `.should.become()`.

Your second test is correct. You can also just use `return` instead of assigning the result to a variable first:

```
bdd.it("Test rejection", function () {
    return q.promise(function (resolve, reject, notify) {
        reject(new Error("test"));
    }).should.be.rejectedWith(Error);
});
```

Comment: Ok but so how to check several conditions like rejected and error with code equal to 31 for sample?

Comment: @Troopers I'm not sure, but I think you could do `return q.promise(.....).catch(function (error) { /* perform ordinary assertions on error */ });`